# Why 'wait' doesn't wait for detached jobs

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I followed this [blog entry](http://arnab.org/blog/quick-and-easy-multicore-sort) to parallelize sort by splitting a large file, sorting and merging.
The steps are:

1. `split -l5000000 data.tsv '_tmp'`
2. `ls -1 _tmp* | while read FILE; do sort $FILE -o $FILE & done`
3. `sort -m _tmp* -o data.tsv.sorted`

Between step 2 and 3, one must wait until the sorting step has finished.
I assumed that `wait` without any arguments would be the right thing, since according to the `man` page, if `wait` is called without arguments `all currently active child  processes  are  waited  for`.

However, when I try this in the shell (i.e. executing steps 1 and 2, and then `wait`), `wait` returns immediately, although `top` shows the `sort` processes are still running.

Ultimately I want to increase the speed of a script with that, so its not a one time thing I could do manually on the shell.

I know `sort` has a `--parallel` option since version 8, however on the cluster I am running this, an older version is installed, and I am also curious about how to solve this issue.

Comment: `ls ... | while read FILE` is wrong. Use `for FILE in _tmp*; do` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple test case reproducing your problem:

```
true | { sleep 10 & }
wait
echo "This echos immediately"
```

The problem is that the pipe creates a subshell, and the forked processes are part of that subshell. The solution is to wait in that subshell instead of your main parent shell:

```
true | { sleep 10 & wait } 
echo "This waits"
```

Translated back into your code, this means:

```
ls -1 _tmp* | { while read FILE; do sort $FILE -o $FILE & done; wait; }
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the `bash` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell).

So when you pipe to `while`, a subshell is created. Everything else in step 2 is executed within this subshell, (ie, all the background processes). The script then exits the while loop, leaving the subshell, and `wait` is executed in the parent shell, where there is nothing to wait for. You can avoid using the pipeline by using a [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
while read FILE; do 
    sort $FILE -o $FILE & 
done < <(ls -1 _tmp*)
```